# Verticaly align a group of buttons between two stacked selects in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm implementing a permission-to-role assignment screen using Bootstrap 3 modal. [Please, see a demo of current state](http://plnkr.co/edit/28hFWNgjXgzqT68SCRNI?p=preview) in full screen, so the selects are not stacked under each other, but aligned aside. As you see, now the buttons are sticked to the top, but I want to place them in one columnt at the center of modal:

[image]

The code is trivial, [check plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/28hFWNgjXgzqT68SCRNI?p=preview) for details:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Role permissions</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
      <label for="availablePermission">
        Available permissions
      </label>
      <select id="availablePermission" class="form-control" size="14">
        <optgroup label="General">
          <option value="0">Change password</option>
          ...
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
      <label for="existingPermission">
        Assigned permissions
      </label>
      <select id="existingPermission" class="form-control" size="14">
        <optgroup label="General">
          <option value="1">View users</option>
          ...
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I've tried flexbox for middle column with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` but the buttons didn't move a pixel. `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` does not work either. Is it possible to beautifuly centrify them without using hard-coded dimensions?

Comment: Does this article offer any value? http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

Comment: I know that I can specify fixed heigth for buttons wrapper and use negative margin, but why flexbox is not working? I thought it's a modern way of doing vertical align...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working with flexbox, <strike>though losing a bit of adaptiveness: try changing the width - selects won't stack vertically now :(</strike> Adding a `@media` query (similar to the one for Bootstrap's `*-md`) will fix this.

```
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .flex-row {
      display: flex; 
    }
  }

  .flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Qo5tiiHlM7FedTbFOHl)

Comment: Thank you very much for your priceless effort, Aiwan, but I have already managed to make it working with flexbox too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably know the height of the 2 buttons, you can do this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
width: THEWIDTHpx;
height: THEHEIGHTpx;
```

Also you need to put `position: relative;` to the row. This will center the box with 2 buttons perfectly in the middle of the row.

If you're using floats to put divs next to each other, make sure the row has a clearfix.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Zenorbi! Never thought about floats. I see bootstrap uses them. What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you don't clearfix the row, the row will have 0 height, because floats don't participate in the containers layout. Because it has height 0, the absolute positioning relative to the row would give unwanted results.

Comment: But actually I do not know the height of the buttons block. There may be three of them later, or four.

Comment: Can I force the height of second column to be the same as the height of third and first? Maybe then flexbox will work? I noticed the second column only wraps content, not spans the whole available height.

Comment: In that case, this will be a little bit harder. There is a way to do this in IE9+ using top: 50%; left: 50%; transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); without the width, height, right, bottom and margin, but if you need IE8, you need the inline-block hack: http://codepen.io/GuillaumeGautier/pen/mIwhu

Comment: If you really want to use flexbox, you can use the align-items: stretch; For more info on all of the flexbox things: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/